# Why does nothing display when I run my java code?

Tags: java, compilation, javac

When I run my java code on one computer it works fine but on the other nothing displays.
When I type java CircleComputation it just returns to command line with nothing displaying but when I copy the file to another computer it works.  Both have java installed and both have Path set.  I can't find any difference in the computers.

Here is the code (not that it matters as I tried multiple programs):

```
/*
 * Print the area and circumferencee of a circle, given its radius double.
 */
public class CircleComputation {  // Saved as "CircleComputation.java"
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      // Declare variables
      double radius, area, circumference;
      final double PI = 3.14159265;
      
      // Assign a value to radius and height
      radius = 1.2;
     
      
      // Compute area and circumference
      area = radius * radius * PI;
      circumference = 2.0 * radius * PI;
      
      // Print results
      System.out.print("The radius is ");  // Print description
      System.out.println(radius);          // Print the value stored in the variable
      System.out.print("The area is ");
      System.out.println(area);
      System.out.print("The circumference is ");
      System.out.println(circumference);
   }
}
```

Comment: Dumb question from me maybe, but are you sure you don't have an outdated .class file which didn't have the part where you print and you just modified the source without recompiling it?

Comment: I don't think it's accurate that "nothing displays."  Probably you are getting an error but you don't notice.  For example, if the window closes too quickly and you don't see the error message.  Please describe exactly what you do to run this program.  Try to run it in a window and make sure the window stays open.  Also type "java -version" and tell us what gets printed.

Comment: How do you run it? try to add `System.in.read();` in the end to prevent the program to close till input

Comment: Also, get rid of the extraneous code, use a simpler example for the code. For instance, use System.out.println("Hello world") and use a different file name. Show us the exact commands you're using on your command line to compile and run the code. In addition to "java -version", please tell us what kind of shell your command line is running on each computer.

Comment: Did you compile java program before running it?

Comment: This is what is being used to compile and run and the output (nothing):
 
PS C:\Users\jeremy.brown\OneDrive - EECD EDPE\CS 120\Example> javac CircleComputation.java

PS C:\Users\jeremy.brown\OneDrive - EECD EDPE\CS 120\Example> java CircleComputation

PS C:\Users\jeremy.brown\OneDrive - EECD EDPE\CS 120\Example>

Comment: And I am compiling it when it is copied to the new cpu, creating the new .class file so it is not an old .class file

Comment: java -version was 17. something.  I don't have access to the second computer at this moment but checked that when I did have access

Comment: And I also tried it with simpler code that just had a println() statement but got the same result.